# java.net.ConnectException when running IntelliJ debugger

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I am trying to debug my Java server with IntelliJ. Every time I start the debugger it shows:

> Error running game debug: Unable to open debugger port :
>   java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect"

I switched off the firewall for Windows, as well as my antivirus scanner, but it's still showing the error.

[image]

Comment: Did you add command line arguments mentioned in the first line to your java server command line?

Answer (score 0):

Connection refused can be happened due to many reasons. It can be due to firewall or proxy. Please check in the Internet Connections whether you are using any proxy or not. If you are using any proxy, you have to use proxy through that you can create connection.